# iOS App Rejected EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) - Unable to Reproduce Error

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

My app was rejected from the review based on the error log:

```
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000048
VM Region Info: 0x48 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4372316088
```

I am unable to reproduce the crash on any of the devices/simulators. I was running various instruments like Zombies and Address Sanitizer, but nothing was found. The app is build for iOS 12.1 and works fine on all tested devices.

Is there a way to discover the origin of the issue please? I came across thread in Apple Dev forum with similar error report pointing to known issues with SFNetwork using iOS 12, but my app does not use CFNetwork. What would you suggest please?

Thank you

Part of the error log from the app review is below:

```
{"app_name":"xxxxx","timestamp":"2019-11-10 17:11:55.07 -0800","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"xxxxx-735520498fee","adam_id":1452107056,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.olaszStudios.xxxxx","share_with_app_devs":true,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)","incident_id":"19AC53EB-8539-487A-91E0-BAE0C1C46053","name":"xxxxx"}
Incident Identifier: 19AC53EB-8539-487A-91E0-BAE0C1C46053
CrashReporter Key:   3ae8b3bfcaad4f26596c08d88637fbf24b0a7633
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             xxxxx [13937]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
Identifier:          com.olaszStudios.xxxxx
Version:             1 (1.0)
AppStoreTools:       11B48b
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.olaszStudios.xxxxx [6192]


Date/Time:           2019-11-10 17:11:54.5395 -0800
Launch Time:         2019-11-10 17:11:54.0933 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000048
VM Region Info: 0x48 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4372316088
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 00000001049c4000-00000001049cc000 [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...y.app/xxxxx

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [13937]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c2174268 0x1c2152000 + 139880
1   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c21729ac 0x1c2152000 + 133548
2   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c21729ac 0x1c2152000 + 133548
3   Sploony                         0x00000001049e7e2c 0x1049c4000 + 146988
4   Sploony                         0x00000001049e7c14 0x1049c4000 + 146452
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b97e2ebc 0x1b8dfc000 + 10383036
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b97e4c8c 0x1b8dfc000 + 10390668
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b97ea4c0 0x1b8dfc000 + 10413248
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fc6810 0x1b8dfc000 + 1878032
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b94573ec 0x1b8dfc000 + 6665196
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fc72f8 0x1b8dfc000 + 1880824
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fc6e04 0x1b8dfc000 + 1879556
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fc7124 0x1b8dfc000 + 1880356
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fc69e0 0x1b8dfc000 + 1878496
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fcaefc 0x1b8dfc000 + 1896188
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b938a028 0x1b8dfc000 + 5824552
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b94705ac 0x1b8dfc000 + 6768044
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fcac34 0x1b8dfc000 + 1895476
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b94704a8 0x1b8dfc000 + 6767784
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8fcaaa0 0x1b8dfc000 + 1895072
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8e3fefc 0x1b8dfc000 + 278268
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8e3ea64 0x1b8dfc000 + 272996
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8e3fc34 0x1b8dfc000 + 277556
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b97e8840 0x1b8dfc000 + 10405952
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b93aaa0c 0x1b8dfc000 + 5958156
25  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba877994 0x1ba86b000 + 51604
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba89c960 0x1ba86b000 + 203104
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba8820f8 0x1ba86b000 + 94456
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba89c61c 0x1ba86b000 + 202268
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b54ac184 0x1b5450000 + 377220
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b5455038 0x1b5450000 + 20536
31  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba8c1540 0x1ba86b000 + 353600
32  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba8c120c 0x1ba86b000 + 352780
33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001ba8c1734 0x1ba86b000 + 354100
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575c7e0 0x1b56b3000 + 694240
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575c738 0x1b56b3000 + 694072
36  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575bed0 0x1b56b3000 + 691920
37  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575701c 0x1b56b3000 + 671772
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b57568bc 0x1b56b3000 + 669884
39  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bf5c2328 0x1bf5bf000 + 13096
40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b97ec6d4 0x1b8dfc000 + 10421972
41  xxxxx                           0x00000001049cd460 0x1049c4000 + 37984
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b55e1460 0x1b55e0000 + 5216

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.network.connections
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b55d7170 0x1b55b2000 + 151920
1   libsystem_dnssd.dylib           0x00000001c92d6158 0x1c92d3000 + 12632
2   libsystem_dnssd.dylib           0x00000001c92d79f8 0x1c92d3000 + 18936
3   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001b7b0e794 0x1b79f0000 + 1173396
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001b7b0f578 0x1b79f0000 + 1176952
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001b7b0f004 0x1b79f0000 + 1175556
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b54ab610 0x1b5450000 + 374288
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b54ac184 0x1b5450000 + 377220
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b545a110 0x1b5450000 + 41232
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b5462340 0x1b5450000 + 74560
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fbfa4 0x1b54f0000 + 49060
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54feae0 0x1b54f0000 + 60128

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fead8 0x1b54f0000 + 60120

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fead8 0x1b54f0000 + 60120

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fead8 0x1b54f0000 + 60120

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b55b55f4 0x1b55b2000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b55b4a60 0x1b55b2000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575c068 0x1b56b3000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5757188 0x1b56b3000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b57568bc 0x1b56b3000 + 669884
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b5a96994 0x1b5a8f000 + 31124
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b5a96874 0x1b5a8f000 + 30836
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b988449c 0x1b8dfc000 + 11043996
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b5bc70b0 0x1b5a8f000 + 1278128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fb1ec 0x1b54f0000 + 45548
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54feaec 0x1b54f0000 + 60140

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fead8 0x1b54f0000 + 60120

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b55b55f4 0x1b55b2000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b55b4a60 0x1b55b2000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b575c068 0x1b56b3000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5757188 0x1b56b3000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b57568bc 0x1b56b3000 + 669884
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c21b7e68 0x1c2152000 + 417384
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c2208df0 0x1c2152000 + 749040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54fb1ec 0x1b54f0000 + 45548
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b54feaec 0x1b54f0000 + 60140

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000002825de5e0   x1: 0x00000001ebade94a   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000010a80f080   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x000000016b438cd8   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001ebade000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000280bc1fa8
   x12: 0x0000000000000002  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000006  x15: 0x0000000000000032
   x16: 0x00000001f27010a8  x17: 0x00000001c2174258  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000002825de5e0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x00000002825d5da0  x22: 0x0000000000000020  x23: 0x00000002801d28e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001eb6dcc21  x26: 0x0000000000000010  x27: 0x4000000280bc0400
   x28: 0x00000001f90b1000   fp: 0x000000016b439510   lr: 0x00000001c21729ac
    sp: 0x000000016b439500   pc: 0x00000001c2174268 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
0x1049c4000 - 0x104acbfff xxxxx arm64  <ecee71b82c9331ebaaf1735520498fee> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
0x104b4c000 - 0x104b53fff GoogleToolboxForMac arm64  <5f9b626d67533ccbae318dd06fe0d217> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/Sploony.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
0x104b60000 - 0x104b6bfff nanopb arm64  <5dc8b13a7cad3f87a317374d4e52967e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/Sploony.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
0x104b7c000 - 0x104bdffff dyld arm64  <571392a7e1e6369f8805c1a141f3c1c5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x104c58000 - 0x104c8bfff SwiftyStoreKit arm64  <b16e5abd43da35c2bef846ae27832694> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/Sploony.app/Frameworks/SwiftyStoreKit.framework/SwiftyStoreKit
0x104ca4000 - 0x104cabfff libswiftARKit.dylib arm64  <428f4bbfa8e43e558832a8665af09444> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/700B5747-0D3B-4948-9DB0-923C97A94020/Sploony.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib
```

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. Your Sploony app is making use of AVFAudio. Symbolicate the crash log so you can see where exactly in your code the problem is happening. Post the relevant code and point out the exact line causing the problem.

Comment: Hi @maddy, thank you for your suggestion! I tried it, but Xcode didn't automatically update the crashlog with symbols. I was following the instructions to use Terminal to try to find the root issue, but it is complaining about the xcarchive is directory, but it doesn't seem to be/have Dsym, or that there is something wrong with the Dsym bundle files and the requested address cannot be found in the Dsym bundles. I will keep trying different methods and will update on the progress. This seems to be the right direction - thank you

Comment: @rmaddy - thanks, it was a good direction. I used ATOS command in terminal and although the audio implementation was according to the documentation and working on local device/simulator - after packing everything and sending to AppStore, the app wouldn't load. I have used "Soundly" cocoapod framework to properly manage sounds within app and it is no longer crashing locally or on technician's device...Thank you!